# PDFJs Blurry PDF on iPAD

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, pdf.js

I am working on a PDJS View within a cordova APP.

Everything works fine except that the pdf is kinda blurry. I know it's somehow because of the retina display but how can i change this oder how do i get the right scale?

Currently I try this

```
pdfFile.getPage(data.page).then(function (page) {


    canvas.width = $('#pdfContainer').width();
    var viewport = page.getViewport(canvas.width / (page.getViewport(1).width));
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    canvas.height = viewport.height;

    var height= $('#pdfContainer').height();



    if (canvas.height > height) {
        canvas.height = height;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(canvas.height / (page.getViewport(1).height));
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
    }

    var renderContext = {
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport
    };

    page.render(renderContext);
});
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Yes still need Help about this?

Comment: @distante urgent? Otherwise i will provide an answer later

Comment: I found a fix that was using the device pixel ratio. Is this the same as yours?  I will post 'my' the answer too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I did for this was first of all deactivate the Image Smoothing:

```
canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d') as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
canvasContext.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
canvasContext.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
canvasContext.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
canvasContext.oImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

And then multiply the `devicePixelRatio` that I find using `window.devicePixelRatio`

```
    if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
        var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
        var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

        canvas.width = canvasWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
        canvas.height = canvasHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
        canvas.style.width = canvasWidth + "px";
        canvas.style.height = canvasHeight + "px";

        canvasContext.scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
    }
```

This also fix the blurry effect for Macbocks with Retina displays.